# Is it possible to set up Crashlytics on iOS without having to install the app on each developer's workstation?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

`Crashlytics` looks like the best crash reporting solution on iOS, but app is noisy and it dirties commits.

Since our `Ad-Hoc` and `App-Store` builds come from a `CI` server we don't need each developer's workstation to upload `.dSYM` files to the server.

Is it possible to configure it so that only the CI server has to deal with `Crashlytics`?

Comment: Short answer, No. I've never found a way of doing it. It's the only downside of Crashlytics I can see.

Comment: Well of course: make the build phase for Crashlytics and Crashlytics initialisation code to trigger only on your CI server. Using environmental variables is probably the easiest way to achieve it. Although maybe I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @A-Live - Yes - Should be ok getting it to run only on the build server using a strategy like this: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/118559-can-i-make-the-dsym-uploading-only-on-release-buil, However I am not sure if the app provides any other mandatory functionality?

Comment: @Robert Anything else would be excessive as you already have the project configured. Enabling the script only for Release builds looks like a good approach, I prefer to have such frameworks disabled at Debug builds anyway.

Comment: You can click the "Run script only when installing" check box. Then the script will only run when archiving. Developers can build and test both in debug and release without installing the app.

Answer (score 2):

We do this in our Run Script phase:

```
if [ ${CONFIGURATION} == "Release" ]
then
  ./Fabric.framework/run <magic> <number>
fi
```

That way, devs use the Debug build normally, but if they want a production-ready build then they can do one.

If you really want it to be only for your CI build, then you can pass additional variables on the xcodebuild command line, call it something like `USE_CRASHLYTICS` and otherwise it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'll have to have each developer install it. It's the same principle with anything with Cocoapods. Just because a project has pods on it doesn't mean that when another developer pulls it from Git they too have access to the pods.